# Android Pull To Refresh Demo On Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

I have implemented pull to refresh using an library from https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh but when i call the demo function(mylistview.demo()) on my listview object from my fragment,the function doesn't execute.

The demo function works when i call it from an onclicklistener so I think the problem has to do with the function being executed before the fragment is loaded. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In which method in the fragment do you call the demo function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the call in OnCreate(), that is probably too early.  Try calling it in OnStart() instead.

I can only assume where you are calling it since you haven't specified it.